# Need to make scada Image's background become transparent

Tags: vb.net

Do anyone have idea on this? For example:

[image: make background transparent on this image]

When insert the image to the ui control, it'a automatic become white background.

Comment: What about creating a transparent image with your preferred image manipulating program?

Comment: It's about conveyor.

Comment: You could use the [Bitmap.MakeTransparent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.maketransparent). It's not clear why your Image doesn't have a transparent background, though. You should probably work on that. Note that, if the Image actually has a transparent background, the transparent pixels will show the background color of the Control where the Image is shown.